Create outlook com-object without mail account
I need to create PowerShell Script to test pst-files for password protections.
I'm trying to do this thru outlook com-object creation.
But this method requires pre-created email profile. How can I get around this requirement?
I know, that I can use Outlook without email profile running command "outlook.exe /PIM NoEmail"
How can I achieve it in my com-object?
Here are some sketches of the script:
$null = Add-type -assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 
$olFolders = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders' -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
#this is what I'm trying to avoid to
$outlook.Logon("Pre-created email profile Name")

$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
#Try to add pst-file to opened profile
$namespace.AddStore($PSTFilePath)

What should I add to my script?

See if following cmdlet helps : https://github.com/lxndrblz/PowerCountPST/blob/master/PowerCountPST.ps1

You cannot do that using Outlook Object Model - while it allows to add PST stores to the active profile (Namespace.AddStore / AddStoreEx), it needs to have at least one existing profile.
Your options are

Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) to create a new profile (IProfAdmin::CreateProfile) and add MSUPST service to it (IMsgServiceAdmin2::CreateMsgServiceEx).
Redemption (I am its author) - it exposes RDOSession.LogonPstStore method that creates a temporary profile (and deletes it when you are done) and returns an instance of the RDOPstStore object. If the store is password protected, it will throw an exception when you try to read folders from it. There is no way to check is PST store is password protected without actually trying to open its child objects.


Dmitry, thank you for such a detailed answer!
